# ADD and COPY with existing relative path fails when building a docker image

Tags: docker, docker-build, docker-copy

**Env:** `Windows 10`, `Docker Desktop (Docker Engine v20.10.6)`

Build of a Docker image fails on command `COPY` (and `ADD`) when its first argument is a relative path starting with `../../`. Error message shows that any path like `../../a/b/c` is replaced with `/a/b/c` and hence cannot be found on the host.

Please, help me to find a way to workaround the problem. In multiple articles and forums I see that Docker can handle relative path properly, but cannot figure out what is wrong in this case.

**Project folder structure**

```
project_root
  first
    container
       Dockerfile
  second
    target
       artifact.file
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM whatever

RUN addgroup -S apprunner && adduser -S apprunner -G apprunner

COPY ../../second/target/artifact.file /home/apprunner/app.file

USER apprunner:apprunner
WORKDIR /home/apprunner
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT blabla
```

Executing command from project_root

```
cd first/container
docker build -q -t my_image_name .
```

get this error

```
...

#7 [4/5] COPY ../../second/target/artifact.file /home/apprunner/app.file
#7 sha256:fefde24bc79e3e0b7a3ba0bf6754187537780b9c30fa81537cb5aea93ef9331c
#7 ERROR: "/second/target/artifact.file" not found: not found
------
 > [4/5] COPY ../../second/target/artifact.file /home/apprunner/app.file:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/second/target/artifact.file" not found: not found
```

Cannot find a reason why the relative path is replaced with an absolute path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `COPY` and `ADD` instructions are relative to the context path passed as last parameter to the command `docker build`.

I solved that issue several times by:

1. copying the out of context file into the context path;
2. copying to the container image by referencing it from context path;
3. removing the (temporary) copied file.

So you will have:

```sh
cd first/container
cp ../../second/target/artifact.file artifact.file
docker build -q -t my_image_name .
rm artifact.file
```

and

```
FROM whatever

RUN addgroup -S apprunner && adduser -S apprunner -G apprunner

COPY artifact.file /home/apprunner/app.file

USER apprunner:apprunner
WORKDIR /home/apprunner
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT blabla
```

Comment: I also use this approach and a bit annoyed with this redundant extra step (copy+remove). What is the problem with Docker?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a problem of docker, but an architectural design.